# Value of $(\log_b2)^0(\log_b5^{4^0})+(\log_b2)^1(\log_b5^{4^1})+(\log_b2)^2(\log_b5^{4^2})+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the value of $$(\log_b2)^0(\log_b5^{4^0})+(\log_b2)^1(\log_b5^{4^1})+(\log_b2)^2(\log_b5^{4^2})+ (\log_b2)^3(\log_b5^{4^3})+\cdots +\infty ,$$ where $b=2000$.

**My thinking:**

Since given Series is GP with common ratio $4(\log_b2)$ so I use the formula of sum of infinity terms of GP
....…..............

$S_\infty$$=\frac{a}{1-r}$
$$=\frac{\log_b 5}{1-4\log_b 2}$$
$$=\frac{\log_b 5}{\log_b 125}$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: For the value of $b$, the common ratio is $4\log_b 2 \approx -1.58$, so the series diverges. Are you sure that's the right value of $b$? Also, did you get this from a math competition (such as ARML)? If so, you should include the source.

Comment: After a bit of searching, the 2000 ARML competition had a problem with that series, except with $b = 2000$ instead of $b = \tfrac{2+\sqrt{26}}{11}$. That's why I thought it looked familiar.

Comment: Can this series is similar to the expansion of $(1-x)^{-n}$

Comment: b should be 2000 ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\log_b2)^n(\log_b5^{4^n})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\log_b2)^n4^n\log_b5$$
$$=\log_b5\sum_{n=0}^\infty(4\log_b2)^n=\log_b5\dfrac{1}{1-4\log_b2}.$$

In the last step, I used the infinite geometric series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\dfrac{1}{1-x}\text{, for } |x|<1.$$

For our problem ($b=2000$), this translates to $|4\log_b2|=|4\log_{2000}2|<0.37<1$.

Comment: This is only true if $\vert 4 \log_{b} 2 \vert < 1$ (see discussion above). The value of $b$ matters.

Comment: @jibounet: The op said  $b=2000$ this implies $|4\log_{2000}2|< 0.37 < 1$. This was assumed in my answer.

Comment: I have also added my approach in detail see plz. But the there is no need of value of B ??

Comment: @AbhishekKumar: Your initial formula was obtained by assuming that $|4log_b 2|<1$. You are not allowed to use the formula if that condition is not true.

Comment: Oh I see thanks